# OOP - If a class creates an instance of a class, does the instance become an object as well?

Tags: oop, class, object

Not to sound like a koan, but just wondering if there are definite rules about classes and objects. I used to think classes as blueprints, and objects as the creation from them. But if a combination of blueprints creates another blueprint, does the latter blueprint become an object as well?

Comment: Your question is very vague. What language is this? You talk about "a combination of blueprints creates another blueprint", which would mean a class creating a new class, not an instance of a class, which is not universally possible in all languages.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding the question... If there's an instance, then that instance is an object.  It doesn't matter what created it.  Anything that's been instantiated on the heap is an instance and is an object.

Comment: Not language dependent. Just OOP in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems a bit philosophical... :) "object" and "instance" are quite synonymous in OOP.

If I understood your question correctly, your doubt is: **"an object is still an object also if created by another class that is not the same that define its type?"**

The answer is **"yes"**, an instance is an object created following the "model" defined by its class, but for many reasons you could instantiate a class in an indirect way, for example a static method (factory method of a factory class, for example) and not directly using `new` statement.

If you want to see some come, an easy example in Java could be:

```
public class MyClass {
    public MyClass(){}
}

public class MyClassFactory{

    public getInstance(){
        return new MyClass();
    }
}
```

In this case the instance is not returned directly by `MyClass`, but from its factory class. however it's an object as well...

Answer (score 0):

In just about every OO environment I know, an instance is the *same* as an object.

It doesn't matter whether the object/instance is created by the client (such as with `new`) or by the class (such as with singletons or factories).

If you're talking about blueprints in the context of classes, then creating blueprints from blueprints is inheritance, not instantiation.

Comment: so if a combination of classes makes a new class, that'll be an inheritance, not an object?

Comment: @Demetriius, yes, that's the basic idea.